# How serious is thyroid swelling while on medication for Graves Disease?

Tags: thyroid, swelling, hyperthyroid

Last month I suffered a bout of severe muscle weakness that led to a diagnosis of hyperthyroidism caused by Graves Disease.

I am currently on medication but yesterday I noticed that a visible bulge appeared on my neck, I have booked an appointment to speak with my doctor about this next week but am unsure as to how urgent or potentially harmful this development is.

The swelling is significant enough to make swallowing somewhat uncomfortable and has remained relatively constant for a couple of days now.

Comment: http://www.btf-thyroid.org/information/leaflets/32-thyroid-nodules-and-swellings-guide